# How can I get all the database names in a sql server instance using tsql?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

How can I get all the database names in a sql server instance using tsql?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.databases
```

Answer (score 17):

----SQL SERVER 2005 System Procedures

```
EXEC sp_databases
EXEC sp_helpdb
```

----SQL 2000 Method still works in SQL Server 2005

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
SELECT name
FROM sys.sysdatabases
```

----SQL SERVER Un-Documented Procedure

```
EXEC sp_msForEachDB 'PRINT ''?'''
```

to know more about database : http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/12/sql-server-2005-list-all-the-database/

Comment: Please note that there is an issue with the stored procedure sp_msForEachDB... it fails for database names containing a dot.

Answer (score 6):

this should work on pretty much any version of sql server

```
USE master;
SELECT NAME FROM sysdatabases;
```

[edit : it could be `SELECT NAME FROM sys.databases` too, microsoft's website says both and i'm not on my windows box to test, sorry!]

you could also use (sql 2005 only)

```
USE master;
EXEC sp_databases;
```

Comment: In case someone is looking for Sybase ASE (tried on 15.7), it's `sysdatabases`.

Answer (score 1):

And for practical use added couple of common filters:

```
  select    database_id, [name] database_name                    
    from  master.sys.databases
    WHERE state <> 6                            -- skip offline
      AND database_id > 4                       -- skip system dbs
      AND HAS_DBACCESS([name]) = 1              -- with User Access
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL 2000

```
use master
select name from sysdatabases
```

or
(no need for use master, includes database_size)

```
exec sp_databases
```